# How do I make webpage != a value higher than 5?

Tags: python

I am starting to learn Python and I was wondering if you guys could give me some help to my problem / improve upon my Coding. This code is basically a login screen where when you input the correct username and password it unlocks a list of url's one could visit. However, I am having trouble finding a way to make it "loop back" when a user inputs a value that is higher than 4. Could any of you help?

```
import webbrowser
import time

print("Enter Username")
name = input()

while name != 'Admin':
    print("Invalid Username")
    name = input()

if name == 'Admin':
    print("Enter Password")

password = input()

while password != 'Password':
    print("Incorrect Password")
    password = input()

if password == 'Password':
    print("Login Successful")

if name == 'Admin' and password == 'Password':
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Which Webpage would you like to visit? Select Value")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("0. Python Library")
    print("1. ASTA Homepage")
    print("2. Autotask Homepage")
    print("3. Google")
    print("4. Youtube")

webpage = input()

if webpage == '0':
    print("Excellent Choice")
    time.sleep(2)
    webbrowser.open('http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org')

if webpage == '1':
    print("Excellent Choice")
    time.sleep(2)
    webbrowser.open('https://www.asta.com.au/')

if webpage == '2':
    print("Excellent Choice")
    time.sleep(2)
    webbrowser.open('https://ww6.autotask.net')

if webpage == '3':
    print("Excellent Choice")
    time.sleep(2)
    webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com.au')

if webpage == '4':
    print("Excellent Choice")
    time.sleep(2)
    webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com')
```

Comment: Why do you not use the same concept you used when reading the password?

Comment: @JeroenHeier I attempted that however, since there are multiple options, it wouldn't work for me. However I did find a fix. I added this to my code: while webpage > 4:
    print("Please Enter a Valid Value")
    webpage = int(input())

Comment: you could keep urls in dictionary or list and use `for` loop to display menu and use one line to select url from dictionary. This way you can add more urls to list without changing code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change the below part of:

```
webpage = input()

if webpage == '0':
    print("Excellent Choice")
    time.sleep(2)
    webbrowser.open('http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org')

if webpage == '1':
    print("Excellent Choice")
    time.sleep(2)
    webbrowser.open('https://www.asta.com.au/')

if webpage == '2':
    print("Excellent Choice")
    time.sleep(2)
    webbrowser.open('https://ww6.autotask.net')

if webpage == '3':
    print("Excellent Choice")
    time.sleep(2)
    webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com.au')

if webpage == '4':
    print("Excellent Choice")
    time.sleep(2)
    webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com')
```

To:

```
webpage = input()
while int(webpage) > 4:
    webpage = input()
if webpage == '0':
    print("Excellent Choice")
    time.sleep(2)
    webbrowser.open('http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org')

if webpage == '1':
    print("Excellent Choice")
    time.sleep(2)
    webbrowser.open('https://www.asta.com.au/')

if webpage == '2':
    print("Excellent Choice")
    time.sleep(2)
    webbrowser.open('https://ww6.autotask.net')

if webpage == '3':
    print("Excellent Choice")
    time.sleep(2)
    webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com.au')

if webpage == '4':
    print("Excellent Choice")
    time.sleep(2)
    webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com')
```

Comment: This will be crashed when input value is not a number.

Answer (score -1):

This works

```
webpage = input()

while not webpage.isdecimal() or int(webpage) not in range(0, 5):
    print("unacceptable number.")
    webpage = input()

print("Excellent Choice")
time.sleep(2)
webbrowser.open(['http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org', 'https://www.asta.com.au/', 'https://ww6.autotask.net', 'https://www.google.com.au', 'https://www.youtube.com'][int(webpage)]
```